# Redirection in angular 2 seems not break the execution

Tags: angular

I'm developing a web app in angular 2 and I have some problems trying to check if the user is logged in or not.

To check that, I have a "LoggedInStatus" service and inside each constructor I check if it's false.

```
constructor(
    private loggedStatus  : LoggedInStatus,
) {
    if (this.loggedStatus.loggedIn == false) {
      console.log('Before redirection');
      console.log('loggedIn: ' + this.loggedStatus.loggedIn);
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      console.log('After redirection');
    }

// ....

}
```

The problem is that I have a redirection and seems not to redirect properly. The executions continue and it supposes to redirect to the login screen.

That's my console log:

```
Before redirection
this.loggedStatus.loggedIn: false
After redirection
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong? Any help?

Thanks,
Ferran

Comment: what you are doing wrong: you don't provide the plunkr which reproduces the problem

Comment: You don't have the router in your constructor in your code. Is this just to shorten the code or is it really not present?

Comment: is it best practice to call the router directly versus redirecting to a url?

Comment: @Sebas Yes, this just changes the view and won't reload the index file with all its resources.

Comment: @Dinistro is to shorten the code, sorry

Comment: @Sebas can you explain a little bit more the difference with some code. I'm really new in angular 2. Thanks

Comment: Could you try catching any errors of the router promise? `this.router.navigate(['login']).catch(err =>  { 
 console.log(err);
})`

Comment: Also, you should consider putting this code in a auth guard? See an example here - https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-authentication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.

In my template I was checking the *User Type* from an *User* object that in case that the user was logged out it will never exist on my *loggedStatus* service, and this caused the error.

```
<button *ngIf="loggedStatus.user.UserType == 'Admin'">Action</button>
```

I've solved the problem doing this check on the component using a variable  called *isAdmin*:

**Component**

```
// Check if is admin
if (this.loggedStatus.loggedIn == true) {
   this.isAdmin = this.loggedStatus.user.UserType == 'Admin' ? true : false;
}
```

**Template**

```
<button *ngIf="isAdmin">Action</button>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It will most likely continue executing the code after the `router.navigate()` call.

Simply add `return` after calling it.

```
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
console.log('After redirection');
return;
console.log('this IS dead code, we will never get here');
```

Comment: As far as I understand the question, it does not redirect at all, so a return will not change anything.

Comment: Thanks @Martin but doesn't work Dinistro he's right. It does not redirect at all.

Comment: do you have a login entry in your router?

Comment: the angular tutorial at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html seems to use a leading slash before the route

Comment: @Sebas -- yes if it is a root route it will need to have a preceding slash. I have updated my example to include this.